# Cloud Message Send reports decreased

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

We have implemented Push Notification with FCM for native iOS app and Android app. The system works fine. Check the statistics in the Firebase console (Cloud Messaging -> Report)  the number of "Sends" is about 1,767,740 before 2/17.
We see a sudden drop in FCM sent counts in the iOS FCM "Reports" dashboard from 2/17. About 561,040. Decreased to 1/3.
Android app works fine. The decreased issue only happen on iOS.

Following the documentation https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/fcm/reports, we check the config and initialize firebase.analytics(). But still no clue.

Does anyone have the same Cloud Message Send reports decreased issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem which occurred around the 17th of March as well. My FCM notifications for iOS users went from 153k sends on the 17th of March to 62k sends on the 21st of March and has been going even lower since. I reached out to Firebase and got a "really helpful!" checklist of things to go over, which somehow doesn't explain the sudden drop-off:

- Expired iOS
- certificates Firebase SDK is not updated Some apps have the wrong Firebase app ID
- Some send requests encountered an error (e.g. invalid credentials,
  expired registration token, etc).
- User's device is turned off, offline, or unable to connect to FCM.
- App crashes when it receives the notification. Crash reporting SDKs
  are the biggest help for detecting this
- Platform-specific battery saving features (e.g. Android Doze) can
  prevent your app from waking up

So sorry I don't have an answer yet but I am talking to my developers and trying to figure out what is causing this issue.